# Checkbox not enabled programatically in android

Tags: android, android-checkbox

**What i am doing**::
I am having a checkbox and a button
onclick of the button i am trying to enable the checkbox

**What is happening**::
Checkbox is not enabled onclick

**Question**::
How can i resolve my issue
Is there any different approach to solve this

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button1;
    CheckBox checkBox1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        checkBox1=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                checkBox1.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Well the Checkbox is never disabled. It should be enabled even before the you click the button...? Do you mean you are trying to set it to checked when the button is clicked?

Comment: @TronicZomB .... yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your `onClick` code with the following:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        checkBox1.setChecked(true);
    }
});
```

I believe you were looking for `setChecked()`, not `setEnabled()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [checkBox.setChecked()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html#setChecked%28boolean%29) method:

```
checkBox.setChecked(true);
```